# AFJSONRequestOperation Crash data parameter is nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I'm experiencing a strange issue that only happens intermittently when I run my app. I'm attempting to pull down JSON from two different sources, using AFNetworking. Occasionally, when the operations are running, the app will crash with `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'` landing on `json_request_operation_processing_queue`.

I'm hoping this isn't a problem with AFNetworking, and I'm just doing something incorrectly. Here are my methods that I think are relavent (JSONManager extends AFHTTPClient):

```
+ (JSONManager *) sharedJSONManager {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _sharedJSONManagerInsance = [[JSONManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:sourceUrl1]];
    });
    return _sharedJSONManagerInsance;
}

- (void) loadOperations {
    _sharedJSONManagerInsance.operations = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:2];
    [_sharedJSONManagerInsance.operations addObject:[self fetchJSON:sourceUrl1]];
    [_sharedJSONManagerInsance.operations addObject:[self fetchJSON:sourceUrl2]];
}

- (void) executeOperations {
    [_sharedJSONManagerInsance loadOperations];
    _sharedJSONManagerInsance.fetchedStories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperations:operations
                                progressBlock:^(NSUInteger numberOfFinishedOperations, NSUInteger totalNumberOfOperations) {
                                    NSLog(@"Finished %d of %d", numberOfFinishedOperations, totalNumberOfOperations);
                                }
                              completionBlock:^(NSArray *operations) {
                                  [[CoreDataManager sharedManager] persistFetchedStories:_sharedJSONManagerInsance.fetchedStories];
                                  _sharedJSONManagerInsance.operations = nil;
                                  NSLog(@"All operations finished");
                              }];
}

- (AFHTTPRequestOperation *)fetchJSON:(NSString*)requestUrl {

    NSURL* jsonUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:requestUrl];
    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:jsonUrl];
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = nil;

    operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
        if([requestUrl isEqualToString:sourceUrl1]) {

            NSArray* arr = [[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"data"] valueForKey:@"children"];
            for (NSDictionary *item in arr) {
                FetchedStory* fs = [[FetchedStory alloc] init];
                fs.title = [[item valueForKey:@"data"]valueForKey:@"title"];
                fs.url = [[item valueForKey:@"data"]valueForKey:@"url"];
                fs.score = [[item valueForKey:@"data"]valueForKey:@"score"];
                fs.source = @"source1";
                [self.fetchedStories addObject:fs];
            }
        }
        else if([requestUrl isEqualToString:sourceUrl2]) {
            NSArray* arr = [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"items"];
            for (NSDictionary *item in arr) {
                FetchedStory* fs = [[FetchedStory alloc] init];
                fs.title = [item valueForKey:@"title"];
                fs.url = [item valueForKey:@"url"];
                NSString* scoreString = [item valueForKey:@"score"];
                if(scoreString != nil && [scoreString length]!=0) {
                    NSRange spaceRange = [scoreString rangeOfString:@" "];
                    scoreString = [scoreString substringToIndex:spaceRange.location];
                    fs.score = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:scoreString];
                    fs.source = @"source2";
                    [self.fetchedStories addObject:fs];
                }
            }
        }
    } failure:nil];

    return operation;
}
```

The crash happens before "All operations finished" logs to the console. Again, this only happens some of the time.

Comment: You can try to put a breakpoint in the success handler and step through it to find which line is generating the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is a bug with AFJSONRequestOperation's responseJSON method. I added a nil check and that seems to be a good bandaid.

Comment: where did you add this nil check?

Comment: This was two years ago so unfortunately I don't remember. I can say I was using AFNetworking 1.x and none of this is relevant to 2.x.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you forget to set HTTP Method Parameter it should be like this:

```
[request setHTTPMethod:@"get"]; // post, patch ....
```